# What is the correct procedure to mark as a possible duplicate?

Tags: discussion, voting, exact-duplicates

Is there some other method to mark questions as possible duplicates than casting a close vote (requiring 3k rep)?

When I see some obvious duplicates, should I add a comment or flag for moderator attention or should I just leave them there and rely that higher-rep'ed part of the community handles the case?

Comment: Note that when deciding which one to vote to close, the date is not essential. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cast a close vote if you have 3k rep.

If you do *not* have 3k rep, flag for moderator attention as it mirrors all the typical close reasons.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/

Answer (score 5):

Posting the link in [our Vote To Close chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117/super-user-vote-to-close) can also help to get attention from users/moderators.

If you like hunting for duplicated questions, [a script I wrote in the past](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1379/see-possible-duplicates-in-question/1380#1380) could be useful...

Comment: @Jawa there is constant checking of the vote to close room by 3k+ users and mods (esp newly elected ones) and thus will get the attention of many users that can vote to close and take the appropriate action

Comment: This is definitely the most efficient method to close a duplicate on SU, as many of us high-rep users check the vote-to-close room frequently, and that way mods don't get inundated with flags for things we can take care of for them.

Comment: The ["_Vote to Close_ chat room" has been **closed**](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6085/vote-to-close-the-vote-to-close-chat-room).

Comment: I know, I played the sad trombone... ='(