# Images abducted by ImageShack.us until we pay the ransom

Tags: support, images

I'm not sure what is involved in the registration of the domain (surely they want some $$).

[image]

This is the question: [iTunes 9 does not show icon in Windows 7 taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/38979/itunes-9-does-not-show-icon-in-windows-7-taskbar)

Can a moderator register the superuser.com domain?

Comment: Related MSO post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75815/what-smart-ways-to-prevent-image-rot-can-we-come-up-with

Comment: I tried to downvote the embedded icecube post only to realize it's an image...

Answer (score 4):

Since Stack Exchange have an account with imgur and that's the destination when you upload images, may as well migrate the images over to imgur.

Or, you can wait for the the team to register the domain:

> #### [Unshackling the shackles from Imageshack shellacking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12776/imageshack-is-showing-unregistered-domain-go-to-http-imageshack-us-to-registe/12777#12777)
>
> ImageShack has apparently changed their policies and now insist upon registering the referring domain onto ImageShack . If the domain is not registered with an ImageShack account then the images will not be shown and the above picture will be substituted.

or get an account at Imageshack

> However, if the end user is a registered ImageShack user, then they will show the image.

Comment: Can't you, as a moderator, register the domain? It doesn't sound as a complicate procedure.

Comment: Moderators don't have email addresses at the site domain, which is what the frogs at ImageShack want @edu

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will have to wait for the team.

Comment: That's probably unlikely unless they see a need to prefer another image host over the one they currently have @edu

Comment: I don't understand. I know that there is a new image host (imageur) but there's a lot of images in other sites prior to the imageur deal.

Comment: There are plenty of other image hosts, but how many need to be so strict about how they display them like imageshack? @edu

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the issue? If you try to solve the issue you surely will spend less energy that trying to avoid it. At least ignore my comments and do something more productive.

1. ImageShack started now with this policy 
2. Was the first result in the Google search suggested in the previous "upload image" dialog
3. It's the second most used hosted image host (according to the SO stats)

Comment: @Eduardo, no matter how complicated it is, it's more complicated than doing nothing. In the absence of any compelling reason for the team to support imageshack, "use imgur" is indeed the right answer. +1 @random.

Comment: "It's more complicated than doing nothing" Indeed! Lazy FTW!

Comment: "other things to do which are more important" isn't the same as "Lazy".

Answer (score 1):

Why can I see that on any Machine, OS or Browser? It is something specific to America?

I'm not a registered ImageShack user...

<sub>Ignore the duplicate questions list under the title, [that's an addon](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1379/see-possible-duplicates-in-question/1380#1380).</sub>

[image]

Comment: Very strange. I'm in Argentina.

Comment: @Eduardo: I can't find a link to register a domain on the site itself either, also, the bit.ly link might be by someone else as you check http://bit.ly/u/imageshack (see http://bit.ly/imageshack-domain+). Also, the IP differ, I find it suspicious that I can find no information about it besides the link and image you provide. Or they might be trying it on certain regions to see the effect before they deploy it to everyone, but as far as I can see on Twitter, reactions aren't that well...

Comment: The page is http://stream.imageshack.us/content.php?page=register_domain but, according to @random, you need and @superuser.com mail account to register the domain.