# Option to show possible duplicates in the review pane?

Tags: feature-request, review, exact-duplicates

Anyone else thing that this would be a useful feature?

Currently, when I look at a question, I use the script that can be found in the accepted answer [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1379/see-possible-duplicates-in-question) to do that. It works pretty well as a rule.

While I understand the comments to that question and answer in that many people will not be using this feature in the general population, the people that are using the review pane are not really the "general population." It would be a shame to review all of these questions, and then try to look for duplicates separately.

I would like the following idea to accomplish this (though I am more than open to other ways of doing it):

Show a short list of possibilities (assuming this option is enabled) with the questions that the system thinks are related. It would be nice if it uses something more than the question title, but I understand if that is hard to implement. Additionally it would be nice if the view was expandable to show some of the text of the question, but this could easily lead to clutter (though having an option to close/minimize this could be a solution to this issue).

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you perhaps expand a bit on what sorts of information would be shown, how duplicates might be detected, etc?

Comment: @nhinkle edited, and clarified.

Comment: Thanks for linking my userscript. I've also started on a very small project that would do exactly what you describe but requires good knowledge of Data Mining, I'm still following that course this year and I am quite busy so my solution to it is quite delayed. A full screen application that shows question bodies next to each other and allows you to go to a question when you think it's a possible duplicate is quite possible with that, but for now it doesn't really exist other than a script that just fetches all the questions and removes stop words from the title... :(

Comment: @TomWijsman if you need some help with something I could probably help.

Comment: @soandos: Working on it but can take quite some time before I have anything that allows one to progress through rather than showing top results, here is an example top result of a comparison of 1000 questions of my old snapshot against all the questions is that snapshot: 95% How do I install a package and its depencies with dpkg? ([322980](http://superuser.com/questions/322980/how-do-i-install-a-package-and-its-depencies-with-dpkg)) Install dependencies for a dpkg package? ([178139](http://superuser.com/questions/178139/install-dependencies-for-a-dpkg-package))